# Calculating the P-value for goodness of fits using Schillings equation

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting, data-fitting

A really nice recent paper in Nature Methods gives a new method for calculating the goodness of fit when the experimental error is not well estimated: http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nmeth.3358.html

I am trying to incorporate that into my fitting routines in MATLAB but my inferior intellect is really struggling with coding the equation right. the equations are given in the figures below
[image: Equations for Gof]
What I want to test is the probability of observing a continuous patch (Rn) given that the largest observed patch was C.

I have made some feeble attempts to code this equation in MATLAB but the results are not impressive. I am struggling with determining An in the above equations because i cannot get the switch between the equations when n>C and n<=C right. The code i have is shown below
**UPDATE: I have updated the code, so it no longer evaluates to negative probabilities. But it is still no working correctly**
If started by creating a simple function which evaluates the sum for n

```
function [ an ] = smalSchill( N, C)
% Small function used to evaluate correlation map statistics

an = 0;
for j = 0:C
    an = an + 2^(N-1-j);
end

end
```

It is then called in my script

```
C = 10; % observered continoues patch of either positive or negative correlation
N = 100; % length(Q); % Number of observations
g = 1; % dummy variable used to index the P-values
Pv = ones(N,1); % Vector holding the p-values. P = 1 for all n <= C

for n = C+1:N
    An2 = 0;
    for j = 0:C

        if n-1-j <= C
            An2 = An2 + smalSchill(n-1-j,C);
            break
        else
            iter_count = n-1-j-C;
            An2 = An2 + iter_count*smalSchill(C,C); %iter_count            
        end
    end
    Pv2(n) = 1-An2/2^n;
end
```

The P-values decay as expected to begin with but as n grows, the P-values converge to 1 which is not correct - they should converge to 0.

cheers!

Comment: Your asking for help translating a paper into Matlab code. To help with that, someone would need to know or read the paper and then cross-check with your code. That's not really a programming problem, and therefore off-topic on SO.

Comment: Hello Donda. I may have phrased my question wrong, so to be clear: I do not ask anyone to read the article and translate it. I added the article to question give the background of my question- not because you need to read it. I am trying to code the an equation from the publication, but i have trouble doing so. Any feedback on what is wrong with my code with respect to the equation would be appreciated - i would particularly like suggestions to how i can avoid so many flow-control statements :)

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any way to help you with that problem without getting into the details in the paper. E.g. you don't explain the symbols in the equations, what is given, what is meant to be computed etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - i also confused the variables myself. so maybe i should have explained it better to my self as well. I will definitely be more careful with my problem description next time :)

Answer (score 1):

I over-complicated everything - and misunderstood the meaning of two of the variables. No wonder my code did work. But i got it to work today

```
N = 1000 % Length of path investigated
patchL = 1:1:20; % length of continious patch which you are interested in testing.
An = zeros(N+1,length(patchL)); % preallocate memory

for zz = 1:length(patchL)
    x = patchL(zz); 

    for n = 0:N

        if n <= x;
            An(n+1,zz) = 2^n;
        else
            An(n+1,zz) = sum(An(n-x:n,zz));
        end
    end
end

AnDist = An(end,:); % supposing last entry (20) is what you are interested in
Dist = AnDist - [0, AnDist(1:end-1)]; % go from cummulative dist to mdf
Dist = Dist./sum(Dist); % normalizing  the mdf
```